# How to generate QR Code of any image

Tags: iphone, qr-code

Is there any API Which can generate QR Code of any image when i will go to read it,it revels the same image.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no direct way to encode an image as QR Code. There are several problems to do this:
- Image would need to be encoded somehow and there's no standard to do that on QR Codes. So any implementation wouldn't work globally.
- An image usually contains hundreds or thousands of kB, while most mobile scanners struggle to decode a QR code with more than a few hundreds bytes (that's at least 1.000 times less information!).

To make it short: It's not possible to do that. Sorry.

A workaround is to upload an image to a server, get a link to that image and create a QR Code with that link. So when the QR Code is scanned, your image is shown on the browser.

[QR Droid](http://q.qr.ai) (for Android) implements this workaround. (QR Droid > Create > Local Image). But I don't think there's any API to do the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Chrome Custom Search (go to chrome:settings -> manage custom search)

Then just create an entry:

```
QR Generator | qr | https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=300x300&chld=H|0&chl=%s
```

then whenever you open a new tab or whatever, you just type qr space your url